# Generic type omitted on method call

Tags: java, generics, annotations

I have an interface with a method of interface

```
<A extends Annotation> A getAnnotation(Class<A> annotationType)
```

the implementation of the class implements the method by wrapping

```
javax.lang.model.element.Element.getAnnotation(...)
```

which has the exact same interface.
when i now try to call my own implementation I get the error `incompatible types: java.lang.annotation.Annotation cannot be converted to myannotation`

bear in mind the `getElement()` function was added for testing and is not supposed to stay

the interface:

```
public interface ElementWrapper<E extends Element> {
  <A extends Annotation> A getAnnotation(Class<A> annotationType);
  E getElement();
}
```

the implementation:

```
public class TypeWrapper implements ElementWrapper<TypeElement> {
  private static final TypeElement element;

  @Override
  public final <A extends Annotation> A getAnnotation(Class<A> annotationType) {
    return element.getAnnotation(annotationType);
  }

  @Override
  public final TypeElement getElement() {
    return element;
  }
}
```

the usage with the problem:

```
public class TheClassIUseTypeWrapperIn {
  public someMethod(TypeWrapper wrapper) {
    MyAnnotation = wrapper.getElement().getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class); // this works fine
    MyAnnotation = wrapper.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class); // this does not work
  }
}
```

i expect my wrapper to work

Comment: "This does not work" in what way? Once you fix the syntax errors, it compiles.

Comment: no it does not compile. save the last 3 code-blocks to files and try it yourself

Comment: Well, I had to add `@interface MyAnnotation{}`, and add a variable to store the `MyAnnotation`, and add a return type to the method; [but then it compiled](https://ideone.com/SbMTlt).